# MySQL: execute the second query only if the first query doesn't return result

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I need this query:

```
SELECT * FROM best WHERE best = 'value' AND lang = 'x' 
   UNION 
SELECT * FROM best WHERE best = 'value' AND lang = 'custom' 
LIMIT 1
```

Basically I just need one record where best = 'value' and `lang = 'x'`, if this record isn't found then I need to execute the second query with `lang = 'custom'`

Is MySQL smart enough to understand that considering there is the LIMIT 1, when the first query of union returns something **he doens't need to execute the second query**?

To have just one query I could do:

```
SELECT * FROM best WHERE best = 'value' AND lang IN ('x','custom') LIMIT 1
```

But with this query I can't say give more priority to record with `lang = 'x'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [ORDER BY FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  best
WHERE
  best = 'value'
  AND lang IN ( 'x', 'custom' )
ORDER BY FIELD ( lang, 'x', 'custom' )
LIMIT
  1
```

This will take care of your "priority" problem :)

Comment: The LIMIT 1 in your first query is part of the second UNION query, so yes both will execute.

Comment: Nope :) You are missing ( & ) around your queries for that LIMIT to limit the whole result. Right now it just limits the second query.

Answer (score 3):

The right anwser is Jan Hančič's answer (+1)

But an alternative solution for more future complex selections and nearly database brand independent may be:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, 1 as preference 
    FROM best WHERE best = 'value' AND lang = 'x' 
   UNION 
  SELECT *, 2 as preference 
    FROM best WHERE best = 'value' AND lang = 'custom' 
) T ORDER BY preference
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @yes123, True. But there is an objection about this? I said that this was not the solution. Just to add information. (I can delete answer if disturbs)

Comment: I think you're answer solves the problem more elegantly.. Thanks for this answer it helped me a lot ;) +1

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap another `SELECT` around your `UNION` where you `ORDER BY lang DESC` and `LIMIT 1`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM best WHERE best = 'value' AND lang = 'x' 
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM best WHERE best = 'value' AND lang = 'custom' 
)
ORDER BY lang DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I imagine X is just a place-holder, it could be anything so your query will not always work. And he is trying to achieve that the second query in the UNION would not run, which your query does not accomplish.

Comment: The decision between running or not running a query is not possible in a declarative language like SQL. For the particular example, my answer solves the priority problem. However, I admit that your solution is more elegant (so +1 for that).