# mysql SELECT. If value in WHERE does not exist, then SELECT based on another (value) WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have such mysql table

[image: CategoryForTest table]

And I have 2 variables/values, for example `FLASH` and `LCD`

I want: if `FLASH` does not exist in the column `name`, then `SELECT ... WHERE` column `name = 'LCD'`. If `FLASH` exists, then does not select based on `LCD`

Wrote such query

```
SELECT 

t1.name AS lev1, t1.url AS url1

FROM CategoryForTest AS t1
LEFT JOIN CategoryForTest AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN CategoryForTest AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN CategoryForTest AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id

WHERE exists (
SELECT name
from CategoryForTest
WHERE t4.name = 'FLASH'
)

UNION ALL

SELECT 

t1.name AS lev1, t1.url AS url1

FROM CategoryForTest AS t1
LEFT JOIN CategoryForTest AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN CategoryForTest AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN CategoryForTest AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id

WHERE not exists (
SELECT name
from CategoryForTest
WHERE t4.name = 'FLASH'
)
AND t2.name = 'LCD'
```

But i get

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [lev1] => ELECTRONICS
        [url1] => url-electronics
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [lev1] => TELEVISIONS
        [url1] => url-televisions
    )

)
```

Expect to see just `[0] => Array`

Comment: how about using two separate query, first for taking those that name is FLASH then if not any result found select those that name is LCD

Comment: Two separate would use additional resources? Not sure how strong it would impact performance (to compare two or one query). I may need one more query to fetch products from another table. So there would 3 queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you.

```
(
   SELECT 

     t1.name AS lev1, t1.url AS url1

   FROM test AS t1
     LEFT JOIN test AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.categ_id
     LEFT JOIN test AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.categ_id
     LEFT JOIN test AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.categ_id

   WHERE not exists (
       SELECT 

         t1.name AS lev1, t1.url AS url1

       FROM test AS t1
         LEFT JOIN test AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.categ_id
         LEFT JOIN test AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.categ_id
         LEFT JOIN test AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.categ_id

      WHERE exists (
         SELECT name
         from test
         WHERE t4.name = 'FLASH'
      )
   )
   AND t2.name = 'LCD'
 GROUP BY t1.categ_id
)
UNION ALL
(
   SELECT 

     t1.name AS lev1, t1.url AS url1

   FROM test AS t1
     LEFT JOIN test AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.categ_id
     LEFT JOIN test AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.categ_id
     LEFT JOIN test AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.categ_id

   WHERE exists (
     SELECT name
     from test
     WHERE t4.name = 'FLASH'
   )
)
```

fidle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d976/3)

Comment: only if i change `FLASH` to `FLASH1` i get long list with `LCD`

Comment: @user2118559 you means to ignore 1?

Comment: I tried to change to `FLASH1` (value that does not exists in mysql to execute query based on `LCD`) and see multiple `LCD`, but need to see only one (as in mysql there is only one `LCD`)

Comment: @user2118559 Do you have any unique field in table to use with group by()?

Comment: so use category_id in group by.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8354045/2118559

```
SELECT 

t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4,
t1.url AS url1, t2.url as url2, t3.url as url3, t4.url as url4

FROM CategoryForTest AS t1
LEFT JOIN CategoryForTest AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN CategoryForTest AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN CategoryForTest AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id

WHERE t4.name = 'FLASH' OR t2.name = 'LCD'
LIMIT 1
```

If `FLASH` exists, then fetch data based on `FLASH`. If `FLASH` does not exist, then fetch based on `LCD`